# How to properly clean burnt connectors?

Tags: power-supply, connection

(This might be the wrong stackexchange page, feel free to migrate the question.)

Recently, I installed a new power supply unit in my PC. However, I forgot to change one of the SATA power supply connectors and used the old one. This caused the SATA connectors of my motherboard and the hard drive to smoke and melt. I immediately unplugged the PSU and the SATA connectors. The hard drive was destroyed by this (I had an exact copy of the contents so there is no problem).

Now, one of the SATA data connectors on the motherboard is fried. There is gouge shaped opening left where the middle copper contact was. (Similarly, the middle contact on the hard drive was destroyed.)

The PSU itself seems to be undamaged.

I am worried that there might be some leftover copper in the contact that could short circuit the SATA port. (There are other ports left that I now use instead.)
Furthermore, everytime I start the PC the fans blow out air with the sickening smell of burnt SATA port.

My question is how to properly clean the burnt SATA port so that I don't have to worry about possible short circuits caused by residual copper.

Comment: Your best bet may be to completely remove it from the motherboard (that should deal with the smell too), though desoldering it may be a bit of a challenge even if you know what you're doing).  However, I wouldn't trust that SATA chipset anymore, if things got hot enough to melt the connector, the chipset itself may be damaged, possibly in a very subtle (but still data-corrupting) way that you won't notice without significant investigation, and would really advocate just getting a new MB instead.

Comment: Isopropyl alcohol, lint-free cloth. You're better off replacing the motherboard, though.

Comment: Hard to answer without an picture of the damage.

Comment: @Moab Unfortunately, the ports are inaccessible "by camera"... I can try to take a picture tomorrow.

Comment: If your eye can see them so can a camera.